# Can I create a Xcode project to debug on MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos

I have an existing project which has it own Makefiles. And it compiles find on MacOS.
Is it possible for me to create a new XCode project but without getting it to compile it under XCode, but I still can use Xcode as my debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Jan/msg00070.html